# Getting The multi-part identifier could not be bound error in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am getting this error after I execute the query. Both tables have a column `ID`. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "CDATA.ID" could not be bound.

Code:

```
INSERT INTO CDATA(Name, Mobile, Email, [Address], [Date]) 
    SELECT Name, Mobile, Email, [Address], [Date] 
    FROM CustomerData
    WHERE CustomerData.ID != CDATA.[ID]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if record already exists in table you may use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO CDATA(Name, Mobile, Email, [Address], [Date])
 SELECT Name, Mobile, Email, [Address], [Date]
 FROM CustomerData
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CData WHERE  CustomerData.ID = CDATA.[ID]);
```

Alternatively `EXCEPT`:

```
INSERT INTO CDATA(Name, Mobile, Email, [Address], [Date])
SELECT Name, Mobile, Email, [Address], [Date]
FROM CustomerData
EXCEPT
SELECT Name, Mobile, Email, [Address], [Date]
FROM CDATA;
```